# Tiled Bitmap in LayerListDrawable as background increases view height

Tags: android, bitmap, nine-patch

To achieve the effect shown in the image below, I combine a nine-patch and a noise bitmap (semi-transparent) in a layer-list, like so:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
  <item>
    <nine-patch android:src="@drawable/actionbar_bg_patch" />
  </item>
  <item>
    <bitmap
        android:src="@drawable/actionbar_bg_noisetile"
        android:tileMode="repeat"/>
  </item>
</layer-list>
```

However, the view (height="wrap_content") is then stretched to the height of the noise bitmap - which is higher than the content even on the Galaxy Nexus.

**Is there a way to crop/clip the bitmap in the layer-list while still repeating it?**

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Have you tried to create this bitmap for various sizes (ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi)?